# How can I use Boost Log with CMake? Find_Package Error

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to use Boost log in a CMake project but I get an error when reloading CMake.

Here is my CMake:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(MyProject)
add_executable(MyProject)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS program_options system log filesystem REQUIRED)

if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    LIST(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -O3")

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProject ${Boost_LIBRARIES}

endif ()
```

Everything was working mighty fine until I added `log` to `FIND_PACKAGES()`

Now, after having added `log` to `FIND_PACKAGES`, I get the following CMake output:

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_log"
  (requested version 1.71.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_logConfig.cmake
    boost_log-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_log" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_log_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_log" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I cannot find those files (-config.cmake) for `log` anywhere and I don't know how to get them. I do have those files for `program_options`, `system` and `filesystem` packages.

Comment: ***CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)*** Is odd for using boost-1.71

Comment: I am actually running version 3.19.2.

Comment: Setting this value too low can cause different behavior. CMake 2.8 was released in 2009

Comment: I have tried updating the value to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure about `CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)`. However, for what it's worth, I use:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
```

see [CMP0074](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0074.html). Which may be a part of your problem.

In your place I would also use:

```
project (MyProject)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MyProjectMain.cpp}

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -O3)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem program_options log_setup log)
if (Boost_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
      PRIVATE
      Boost::system
      Boost::filesystem
      Boost::program_options
      Boost::log_setup
      Boost::log)

endif ()
```

This uses the relatively new `target_*`  CMake instructions and works for me, see: [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)